# How do I view all shares of my posts?

Tags: facebook

On my Facebook page it tells me I have had 11 shares.  There is a link to view all shares.  I click on this link and I only see 2 shares.  Why am I seeing only 2 out of 11 shares?

Answer (score 2):

You can only view the shares that you have access to - that is, shares by your friends, or shares which are public.

I believe in testing, [page admins could see all of the shares](http://blog.hubze.com/2011/09/facebook-update-view-who-shares-your-posts/) of their content, but this has been locked down.